# VBS: Counting number of items in an Array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

How could I investigate simply the number of items in a given array.
I used this code, but it's a bit laborious

```
myArr=Array("frog", "cat", "bat", "rat", "horse")
 for i=0 to UBound(myArr)
 ' Msgbox i +1 & ".item: " & myArr(i) 
 next
Msgbox i & " items in this array:" & vbcrlf & Join(myArr)
```

Thanks

Comment: One of those rare submissions where the answer is within the question. :)

Answer (score 11):

Umm... you have it in your code. `UBound(Array)` returns the upper bound, which is the highest existing item. `UBound(myArr) + 1` is its length, because the index is zero based.

Comment: Oh what a fool I've been ... Thanks Ѿ

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as the solution! Thanks

Comment: This solution is wrong, on an empty array you will get every time a size of 1,which is not what you want!

Answer (score 1):

`Msgbox (ubound(myArr) + 1) & " items in this array:" & vbcrlf & Join(myArr)`

EDIT: While you are using `ubound` already, why do you need a loop & a variable `i` to count.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is

```
Msgbox (UBound(myArr)-LBound(myArr)+1) & " items in this array:" & vbcrlf & Join(myArr)
```

This gives you the right item count also when your array is empty.

Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574874/1426827