# Finding the length of a VBA array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom Excel function that is supposed to take a range and count the number of values, where some cells may contain multiple `/`-delimited values, each of which must be counted. Here's the function:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function COUNT_RACKS(rack_range As Range) As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim split_str As Variant
    Dim len_str As Integer
    total = 0
    For Each cell In rack_range.Cells
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            If InStr(cell.Value, "/") <> 0 Then
                split_str = Split(cell.Value, "/")
                len_str = Len(split_str)
                total = total + len_str
            Else
                total = total + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    COUNT_RACKS = total
End Function
```

The trouble is, it's throwing `#VALUE!` errors. In stepping through the function in the debugger, it seems like there's a problem with the line `len_str = Len(split_str)`. I say this because whenever I get to this line in the debugger, it immediately stops debugging and does, essentially, an `F5`. Obviously there's one or more bugs in my code, but without my debugger being willing to show me the errors, how can I debug it?

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: See here for how to the number of elements in an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124669/number-of-elements-in-a-single-dimension-variant-array-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks. It seems that VBA terminology is so different that I couldn't find it when searching using more normal methods. And who would have thought that the Len function would work on strings but not arrays?

Comment: Careful with the snarks. Javascript isn't any more "normal" than VBA is. The `Len` function is found in the `VBA.Strings` module of the standad library (its members have global scope, that's why you don't need to qualify them). You can browse these modules and their members using the IDE's *Object Browser* (F2). Being a `VBA.Strings` function, makes complete sense that it works on... strings.