# How to determine the length of an array in VBA

Tags: vba

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 students1 = Array(423.5482, 425.6641)
```

Now I would like to get the length of this array. However, if I try this:

```
 MsgBox(students1.Length)
```

I get the error that an object is required. Any thoughs on how I can get the length?

Comment: have you researched this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get length of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574814/get-length-of-array)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574814/get-length-of-array

Comment: google "get array length vba" its the second link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use UBound and and Lbound

```
MsgBox Ubound(students1)-Lbound(students1)+1
```

Comment: This will not work on dynamic arrays because UBound() will error out

Comment: This question was not about a dynamic array but a set array.

Comment: The Answer code is correct ONLY IN THE CASE THE ARRAY IS DEFINED AND NON-EMPTY. If you really want to generically get the size of an Array, then here is a robust solution that handles all the edge cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574814/get-length-of-array/68614881#68614881