# How to find the length of an array vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```
Sub Test4()

Public Function GetLength(a As Variant) As Integer
   If IsEmpty(a) Then
      GetLength = 0
   Else
      GetLength = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1
   End If




End Function
```

Essentially trying to find the length of two arrays, and am a little confused on how to use this code to do so. Unsure of what to place where and how to make it work without errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are going to have check `IsEmpty` for `a`, you may also want to check whether `Not IsArray` for it too.

Comment: Thank you for the help, will get back if I come across any difficulties

Comment: @Lex, if it has solved your issues, you should return the favor and accept an answer. And upvote those that helped once you able to do so. It's simply how the website works =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get length of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574814/get-length-of-array)

Answer (score 2):

Are you confused because you need to seperate the function from your sub? You should call that function something like:

```
Sub Test4()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
    If IsArray(arr) Then Debug.Print GetLength(arr)
End Sub

Public Function GetLength(a As Variant) As Long
    GetLength = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1    
End Function
```

I left out `IsEmpty` if you are to always initialize `arr`, but put it back if you want to. Just in general, if you are confused on how to call functions and return their values. Have a look at the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures).

Comment: @Chronocidal, the idea of `Not IsArray` is a good one. Implemented if you don't mind. Though, I'd personally check it before returning any value since OP wants to check arrays and arrays alone.

Answer (score 0):

The Parameter `a` represents your Array.  The function will return the length of the *first* dimension of the array it receives as an Argument:

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Split("A,B,C,D,E,F", ",") 'create an Array of Length 6
    MsgBox GetLength(MyArray) 'Output the length of the array, "6"
End Sub
```

As noted, this may give unexpected results for a 2D array:

```
[[A][B][C]
 [D][E][F]]
```

This is a 2-by-3 array, so `GetLength` will tell you that the length is *2*.  However, the number of **elements** in the array is *6*

(Note - if this is being used in VBA, then there is no advantage to using `Integer` instead of `Long`, and I would recommend you change that line - especially since `UBound` and `LBound` both return `Long`s.  With too large an array, you could get an Overflow error!)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give this a go